# Where can I find free security and derivative pricing software?

Tags: risk-management, pricing

I am looking for a free derivative valuation software that can compute value and sensitivities. It should be easy and straightforward to use, e.g., I can get results by supplying market data and trade information and clicking a button.

Comment: Why would anyone give you something like this for free?!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the FinPricing software that has pricing functions you are asking, plus curve and volatility surface constructions. It is free now.

Comment: Hi Dora, never heard the name. Is it a company name or a product name? Appreciated if you can send me a link. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is the company name. Go to finpricing  dot com to download the product.